# How to add a button on top of keyboard on IONIC4

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4, ionic-native

I've been trying to add a "SUBMIT" button on top of the keyboard using Ionic4 but no luck so far. Is that possible?

I'm using the Ionic Native Keyboard Plugin and I've added the `<preference name="KeyboardResize" value="false" />` on my config.xml

This is what I have in the bottom of my html

```html
<ion-footer>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-button style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 5px; z-index: 2;" expand="full" type="submit">Submit Review</ion-button>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Also is there a way to make it so the keyboard can't be dismissed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for reference in case someone has the same issue, the solution is to import `KeyboardResizeMode` on the component you have your keyboard.

```
import { Keyboard, KeyboardResizeMode } from '@ionic-native/keyboard/ngx';

constructor(private keyboard: Keyboard) {}

// On the ngOnInit()
ngOnInit() {
   this.keyboard.setResizeMode(KeyboardResizeMode.Body);
}
```

You can't pass the `setResizeMode` as a `string`, even thou on the documentation says so, it needs to be as a property of `KeyboardResizeMode`.